# Загрузка массива целиком на лист

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть реализации загрузки на лист из базы msql построчно:

```
function readDatatest() {
// Выгрузка баз на страницы --------------------------------------------
 var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
 var stmt = conn.createStatement();
 var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM ' + "posts_info");
 var metaData=results.getMetaData();//Получаем целую таблицу
 var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount();// Количество столбцов
 var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
 var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('test');
 sheet.clearContents();// очищаем лист перед загрузкой
while (results.next()) {
 arr=[];//создаём пустой массив
 for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {
   arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
 }
 sheet.appendRow(arr);
}
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать выгрузку целую базу, через массив (не построчно)
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Не уверен, но по-моему у этого коннектора нет дампа, а только курсор. Поэтому только так

```js
function readDatatest() {
  // Выгрузка баз на страницы --------------------------------------------
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var results = stmt.executeQuery('SELECT * FROM ' + 'posts_info');
  var metaData = results.getMetaData(); // Получаем информацию о таблице
  var numCols = metaData.getColumnCount(); // Количество столбцов
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('test');
  sheet.clearContents(); // очищаем лист перед загрузкой
  const data = []; // Данные для вставки
  while (results.next()) {
    const row = []; // создаём пустой массив
    for (var col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
      arr.push(results.getString(col + 1));
    data.push(row);
  }
  if (data.length)
    sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

Возможно, у вас слишком большой набор данных, попробуйте выбирать данные частично, напримр построчно по 1000 строк

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1, 1000`

следующий запрос

`SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1001, 1000`

и т.д.

Не думаю, что это как-то ускорит общее положение дел, но вы сможете избежать рутины в загрузке предыдущих данных.

Comment: Спасибо, так пробовал. Всё равно долго работает. была идея дополнять ранее внесённые данные, но не могу разобраться как загружать базу с нужной строки? При нынешнем исполнении с самого начала идёт загрузки базы. Если есть соображения помогите пожалуйста. Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 0):

аналогично искал решение по выгрузке данных из MySQL через JDBC, метода загрузить массив я не нашел, но можно получать сразу всю строку в виде объекта JSON. Это несколько ускоряет.

Посмотрите в сторону JSON_OBJECT и JSON_ARRAY, если данных не очень много, то можно с помощью JSON_ARRAY получать за 1 запрос всю информацию, затем уже с ним работать.

Если данных много, то можно получать данные частями (если времени скрипта не хватает на выполнение). Суть заключается в том, чтобы записать в таблицу последний элемент (порядковый номер или ID и т.п.) на который успел обработать скрипт и создать тригер на повторный запуск скрипта.

При повторном запуске скрипта, получаем из таблицы значение на чем остановились и продолжаем, если данные все обработаны на последней итерации в таблицу фиксации итераций вносим соответствующую информацию и триггер на запуск нового уже не запускаем. Возможно, это не совсем точно, но суть думаю Вы поняли.

Мой пример работы с mysql с помощью JSON_OBJECT

```
function jdbc_sinc_id_files() {

  //Запрос к БД
  const queryStr = `SELECT JSON_OBJECT('download_id', download_id, 'filename', filename, 'mask', mask) FROM oc_download`;

  //Отправляем запрос к БД
  let resp = jdbcQuery(queryStr);

  //Записываем в переменную массив данных из БД
  let arrResult = resp.arrResult;
}

function jdbcQuery(query) {

  //Устанавливаем соединие с БД
  let stmt = jdbcMysqlConnect();

  //Лимит результатов
  // stmt.setMaxRows(10);

  //Дата и время начала операции для отслеживания времени работы скрипта
  var start = new Date();

  //Объект с результатами
  let result = {};

  //Время начала
  result.start = start;

  //Запрос на SQL к БД
  var rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

  //Временная точка - фиксируем выполнение запроса
  var end = new Date()

  //Выводим время в лог
  Logger.log('Время выполнения запроса: %ss', (end - start) / 1000);

  //Создаем переменную для записи результатов в цикле из БД
  let resultJSON;

  //Создаем пустой массив для результатов
  let arrResult = [];

  let i = 0;

  

  //В цикле получаем из БД каждую строку в запросе
  while (rs.next()) {
    resultJSON = rs.getString(1);                         //Получаем строку из БД в формате JSON
    resultJSON = JSON.parse(resultJSON);                  //Парсим JSON (return Object)
    if (!i) {//Если это первая итерация цикла (i=0), то
      arrResult.push(Object.keys(resultJSON).reverse());  //Добавляем в массив заголовки из Ключей объекта
      i++                                                 //Инкременируем счётчик
    }
    arrResult.push(Object.values(resultJSON).reverse())   //Добавляем значения ключей в массив результатов
  }

  //Добавляем к объекту массив с результатами
  result.arrResult = arrResult

  //Временная точка - фиксируем время чтения данных из БД
  var end = new Date();

  Logger.log(`Массив получен, времени прошло с начала: ${(end - start) / 1000}s, прочинано строк ${arrResult.length}`);

  rs.close();

  stmt.close();

  return result
}
```